# Guzzle *70 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: php, guzzle

Hi tried to do a simple guzzle request using GET method but I'm getting an error of

> [error] 16#16: *70 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.26.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /dologin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/login"

Not sure why but when I try to do a simple CURL request via terminal and PHP script the response was correct and I was able to retrieve the data. below are my code for the Laravel Guzzle

```
 $request_url = "http://myendpoint/GETDATA/$UserID/";
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $res = $client->request('GET', $request_url); // <-- This one throws an error
```

But on a PHP script I have this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://myendpoint/GETDATA/$UserID/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
// further processing ....
echo "\n" . $server_output . "\n";
exit();
```

But this one returns the response. Only through Guzzle that I'm experiencing the error. Any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: There is no function `env`, but `getenv`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php maybe that is why it is not working :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I know this is in Laravel which exist. So it's not really the problem here. The value for $request_url is correct upon checking but when running the $client->request thats where the issue occur

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, never used Laravel :( Is `"http://myendpoint/GETDATA/$UserID/"` equal to `env('MY_ENDPOINT')."/GETDATA/$UserID/"`?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch yes that is correct. I tried the same URL using CURL request and it's working. Not sure what is happening on the Guzzle part since. $client->request is under GUzzle

Comment: What verion of GuzzleHttp do you use?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I think its 6.0

Comment: So what happens when you hardcode it to a form of `$request_url = "http://myendpoint/GETDATA/1/";`? Because if that doesn't work, `env` isn't part of the problem and [should be removed for the purpose of this question](/help/mcve), and if it does, you now know where the real problem is.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans tried hardcoding the URL and same error occured.

Comment: In that case, put that hardcoded url in your question and remove all mention of env, since it's not related to the problem. Keeps the attention focused on what might be wrong, rather than what you already know isn't.